# Infinite Scrolling Photo Banner With HTML and CSS pause animation on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have this infinite scorlling photo banner mad with HTML and CSS following this tutorial -

http://designshack.net/articles/css/infinitephotobanner/

So far it works, but I am wanting it to pause when I hover over any of the images.

Tried putting a `-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;` on the hover states of the images, but it only works on the first image.

Ideally, I ant both rows to pause when I hover over any of the photos.

Here is my codepen -

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPXgbW

Any help will be massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add animation to the wrapping div instead of the first image:

```
.photobanner {
  height: 233px;
  width: 3550px;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}
```

And pause the animation when you hover on the wrapping container:

```
.photobanner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```